# Bootstrap modal works on local site, but not on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fire a 'thank you' modal on page load. It works just fine on my local machine, but when I put it to staging, it won't load.  Currently using a custom Wordpress theme. Any suggestions?

I've read a few similar questions with a variety of answers but nothing seems to be working.

Here's the page where the modal is supposed to fire on page load (staging site): http://ce7.180.myftpupload.com/select-your-plan/thank-you/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Thank you for signing up!</h4>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You just made one of the better decisions of your musicial life. We're honored and excited to have you as a part of our club.</p>
    <p>While you're here, we'd love it if you would take a minute to share Vinyl Me, Please with your friends. All it takes is a click of a button ;-)</p>
    <p>OH, and if you didn't already know, Vinyl Me, Please makes for a <a href="/give-a-gift">great gift</a>. Just sayin'.</p>
    <p class="margin-bottom"><div class="fb-like pull-left margin-bottom margin-right" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/VinylMePlease" data-width="200" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
      <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-url="http://vinylmeplease.com" data-text="I just signed up for @vinylmeplease, the best damn record club out there" data-related="VinylMePlease" data-size="large"  data-hashtags="vinylme">Tweet</a>
      <script>// <![CDATA[
      !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
      // ]]></script> <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="mailto:?subject=Check out Vinyl Me, Please&body=Hey buddy, I just came across this site called Vinyl Me, Please and I think you'd really dig it. Every month they send you a new record pressed exclusively for their members with a custom art print and cocktail pairing. You usually have to request an invite, but you can sign up directly using this link: http://vinylmeplease.com/get-started/. Peace!">Send an email!</a></button></p>
    </div></p>
   <div class="modal-footer"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check for javascript errors? The error message would help a lot.

Comment: There's an error around this bit of JavaScript ~ `String urlDecode(String input) {`. FYI, JavaScript functions don't have return or argument types

Comment: It's likely that `String urlDecode(String input)` is messing up your page as there's an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when trying to load the modal.

Comment: I also get *"undefined is not a function"* around `$('#myModal').modal('show')` but that's probably caused by the previous error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using several versions of jQuery (`1.9.0` and `2.1.3`) in your staging page, loading bootstrap plugins after the first one and loosing 'em right after the second jQuery instance loaded.

Move your `script` tag referencing bootstrap plugins after the loading of the second jQuery instance.

Comment: Looks like that might have done it! I had a jQuery updater plugin that was causing the conflicting versions. Do you have a recommendation on which version is best to use?  Thanks so much!